# what would be the output of this code, it uses strcpy in a constructor?

Tags: c++, class, c-strings, strcpy

Hello I have question about some code.
Is this code supose to work as it is here?

I thought I would need to use #include cstring

I asked my teacher and he told me that the code is good as it is and 
that it should work with #include string

Is this correct? can someone explain me please  ?thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> //strcpy() works with string?
using namespace std;

class libraryBook{

  private:

    char title [80]; //cstring
    int available;

  public:

    libraryBook(char initTitle[]);//cstring as argument

};


libraryBook::libraryBook(char initTitle[]){

  strcpy(title, initTitle); 
  available = 1;

}


int main() {

  libraryBook b1 ("computing"); //what would be the output without changing the code ?

  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Since you're in C++, why not use `std::string` instead of arrays of `char` ?

Comment: What parts don't you understand?  Note: the current code will go horribly wrong if you pass an 80+ character string to libraryBook's constructor, can you figure out why?

Comment: im not supose to change the code :(.The exercise was just about guessing the output.

Comment: I'm confused; your professor said it should work with `<string>`, right? So the @Louen would be correct

Comment: Yea it doesn't make much sense to give you the string library but force you to pass a char array.

Comment: Methinks you want `#include <cstring>`, not `#include <string>` to get `strcpy`. `strcpy` is a good ol' C function and all the ol' C stuff is in headers that start with c

Comment: If you want to copy a string literal `.copy()' is the function

Comment: Like @user4581301 said, `strcpy` is [not in <string>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string)

Comment: Sidenote: `libraryBook(char initTitle[]);` will be a bit more versatile as `libraryBook(const char *initTitle);` You'll be able to eat string literals safely and without errors. In modern Standard C++ `libraryBook b1 ("computing");` is flat-out illegal to protect you from accidentally writing to read-only storage.

Comment: Dunno about your compiler, but my compiler (and my brain) don't like the fact that you are passing a string-literal to a method via a non-const-qualified argument:  `temp.cpp:29:19: warning: conversion from string literal to 'char *' is
      deprecated [-Wc++11-compat-deprecated-writable-strings]`

Comment: ok , got it. I least I'm sure now that it won't work like that .Now I can ask my teacher again to doble check my answer .(thank you for the comments)

Comment: No worries. It's only one letter so I wrote the error off as a typo. It's astounding how easy it is for the human brain to insert a or miss a character.  A good trick to check yourself when the compiler says you've screwed up is to pop *man <name of function>* into google and see what comes back at you. The man pages usually bring up what header to include pretty early. [It's the first line in the synopsis here.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html). For C++ stuff [go to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy). It's a pretty reliable reference.

Comment: If all else fails, [here's a link to an up-to-date draft of the C++ Standard.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/) The Standard's the final word on what is and isn't valid C++, but it's meant to be read by 20th level multi-class Programmer/Lawyers, so don't get upset if it looks like it's written in Martian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, "as is", the program may or may not compile. You need to include `<cstring>` if you want the `strcpy()` function (as pointed out in the comments by @user4581301.

After including `<cstring>`, the output of the program is nothing since you're printing nothing out. Realistically though, you shouldn't be using character arrays in lieu of `std::string` in C++. A demo of your code can be found [here](http://www.cppshell.com/542cm).

Comment: Funny how answers tend to pop up at the same time, even hours after the question was asked.

Comment: @user4581301 I assure you it was purely coincidence :)

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Use `<cstring>` ranther than `<string>`, but even when the header is corrected, the program has no output.

## Discussion

> I thought I would need to use #include cstring
>
> I asked my teacher and he told me that the code is good as it is and that it should work with #include string

You thought right and the teacher is wrong<sup>1</sup>. The [C++ Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.syn) does not guarantee that `strcpy` is made available by including `<string>`.

<sup>1</sup> Sort-of wrong. There are no guarantees that `<string>` provides `strcpy` or a header chain that ultimately includes `<cstring>`, but no one said that it couldn't. Just don't count on it. A file should always include all of the headers it requires<sup>2</sup> to prevent avoidable errors. The teacher may also have been fooled by their brain into seeing a c where there was no c when they told you your code was correct. They may have meant for you to use the old C header `<string.h>`. It's hard to tell.

<sup>2</sup> Sometimes you'll find a header that you'd expect to contain another header instead [forward declares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c) the parts of the other header that it needs to avoid the compile-time overhead of including the other header.

Answer (score 1):

At least in my opinion, your teacher's idea was clearly better. A halfway reasonable starting point would be something like this:

```
#include <string>

class LibraryBook { 
    std::string name;
    int available;
public:
    LibraryBook(std::string const &name, int available = 1) 
        : name(name)
        , available(available) 
    {}
};
```

Then creating a book would look something like this:

```
LibraryBook book("Steal This Code");
```

Since we haven't included any code to write anything out, this won't produce any output (other than returning a code to indicate successful exit).